# How to derive the force from being hit by a tidal wave?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I was wondering how one might write down an expression which estimates the force experienced if a person were to be hit by a tidal wave (perhaps assuming the person could be modelled as a sphere).  I guess you could also use Wagner theory to find the instantaneous force on impact, but this becomes complicated.

I assume that similar to the analytic expression for Stokes drag for a low Reynolds number flow the force would depend on the viscosity and speed of the liquid, since being hit with water would not be as bad as being hit with a more viscous liquid.